# Merging lines to make polygon

Tags: carto, geometry-conversion

I've searched around  but haven't find anything about this topic.
I have several lines that represent the border between adjacent areas, so each area is delimited by several lines. How can I merge the lines to create the polygons representing the areas? Each line has two columns representing the areas that it separates.

Added:

The problem can be divided in two steps:
- Merge lines in a single unified line (ST_LineMerge, ST_Collect, ST_Union)
- Create a polygon from the unified line

Answer (score 2):

In CartoDB you can do this as two steps, first the SQL and then the creation of a new table from the result.

### The SQL

```
SELECT 
  ST_MakePolygon(ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(the_geom))) 
  the_geom, some_id_of_polygon 
FROM 
  tablename 
GROUP BY 
  some_id_of_polygon
```

That should give you a two column result, you wont be able to map it yet. You may also run into a problem if you don't **close** your polygon. Meaning, you need the polygon to end on the same point it started (in the list of vertices). If that is the case, you could fix it with,

```
SELECT 
  ST_MakePolygon(
    ST_AddPoint(
      ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(the_geom)), 
      (SELECT ST_StartPoint(the_geom) FROM tablename 
       WHERE some_id_of_polygon = t.some_id_of_polygon LIMIT 1
      )
  ) 
  the_geom, some_id_of_polygon 
FROM 
  tablename 
GROUP BY 
  some_id_of_polygon
```

### Create a new table

Now, you should be able to create a new table by clicking the link that appears in your table view **Create new table from Query**. If you don't see it right away, click the dropdown **Options** in the upper right and you should see it in there.

Your new table should be a set of polygons and your some_id_of_polygon

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the information. I get "Shell is not a line" message after running the sql query. Any hint? Thanks in advance.